# Nginx не пускает себя на порт 80 (или любой другой)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, virtual-hosts

Лог nginx:

```
bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

Файл виртуалки:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
        ...
}
```

Сижу под root-ом. Когда виртуальному хосту меняю порт (на 3001 например) - выводит ту же ошибку в логах с тем портом, на который только что переписал.

Результат `netstat -plunt | grep 80`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15595/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      15595/nginx: master
```

Результат `lsof -i:80`:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   15595     root    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15595     root    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15596 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15596 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15597 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15597 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15598 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15598 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15599 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15599 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15600 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15600 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15601 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15601 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15602 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15602 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15603 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15603 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15604 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15604 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15605 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15605 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15606 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15606 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15607 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15607 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15608 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15608 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15609 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15609 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15610 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15610 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15611 www-data    6u  IPv4 278914      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   15611 www-data    7u  IPv6 278915      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Вырубаю все `pkill -f nginx & wait $!` и запускаю nginx, натыкаюсь на данную ошибку.

Помогите, что делать, пожалуйста!

Comment: `Вырубаю все pkill -f nginx & wait $! и запускаю nginx` — а если не запускать? Может он у вас каким-то чудом автоматически запускается?

Comment: Ну и спокойствия ради, поискать в конфигах все директивы `listen` и убедиться что там нет чего-то подозрительного.